# What happens if police stops me when driving a rental car and I'm not the authorized driver (US-FL)?

Tags: legal, driving, car-rentals, officials, florida

I rented a car, but didn't want to pay a second driver fee. My spouse is driving the car but I want to know if I'll be in trouble if police stops me when I'm driving.

I know that insurance won't pay in case of accident but will I have other problems if I drive?

I'm in Miami.

Comment: In the US, this would be regulated in state law. I am not sure about Florida, but driving a vehicle without the owner's consent ought to be prohibited in most US states and also other jurisdictions. If the owner incurs a loss as a result of the violation (you have evaded the extra driver fee), the violation is e.g. in Ohio even considered a felony and punishable with at least 6 months imprisonment. If the police would notice or bother to check is of course another question.

Comment: The additional driver fees are much much less in terms of money and much much more in terms of peace of mind than any other option whether it is a police problem or insurance problem.

Comment: If you were stopped, your status would be as if you were driving a friend's car - that is, you are not the owner and _may not be authorized_ to drive the vehicle. God forbid you are involved in a serious accident; you will have a lot of problem (insurance for one, additional liability and other headaches depending on the laws in of the state). As others have mentioned, it would be less expensive to just get the additional driver added to the contract.

Comment: Don't get pulled over!

Comment: I don't want to flag this as "unclear about what you are asking," but I am confused. What are you looking for here, if not insurance. Do you mean will you possibly be charged with a crime just for driving the car?

Comment: You should check with the rental companies whether you'd even have to pay to get your spouse added.. Some always waive the second-driver fee for your spouse, others do if you join their frequent renter program.

Comment: If you rent the car in California they are prohibited from charging the fee, however that's a bit inconvenient if you need it in Miami.

Comment: With some companies (and by law in some states) your spouse is automatically a co-driver. If not, I would most certainly pay the fee. The policeman may not be interested, if you are married, but in an accident the insurance company will be delighted to decline coverage.

Comment: @CGCampbell yes :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could possibly be charged with driving a vehicle without the owners consent, but more importantly if you are not a valid driver then you are driving without insurance.

**Driving without insurance is illegal in Florida.**

You should also be aware that the insurance you don't have doesn't just protect you against damaging the car. In the US, if you seriously injure someone in an accident they can and will come after you for their medical bills, which can run to hundreds of thousands of dollars. This is what your insurance covers you against (amongst other things). Unless you can afford to pay hundreds of thousands of dollars, don't drive without insurance.

Further reading:

- [Car Insurance in Florida](http://www.dmv.org/fl-florida/car-insurance.php)
- [Penalties for Driving Without Insurance in Florida](http://carinsurance.about.com/od/Florida/fl/Penalties-for-Driving-Without-Insurance-in-Florida.htm)

Comment: Hundreds of thousands of dollars? Seems pretty low to me. If you leave someone permanently disabled/disfigured, that could run much higher. http://www.pritzkerlaw.com/amputation/

Comment: It's quote possible to have insurance that covers rental cars and still not be an authorized driver of the vehicle. This would most likely apply to US citizens/residents who have a US auto insurance policy which covers US car rentals. In this case, you could still drive a friend's rented car, and be insured, but not be an authorized driver. The chances of being caught in such a situation are minimal, but if caught, I don't know what the consequences would be.

Comment: I considered that, but I'm willing to bet that most rental vehicle insurance policies only cover vehicles on which you are an authorized driver. Obviously in the end it depends on the individual policy

Comment: Will this also be the case if the op did not purchase insurance from the rental agency but used his existing car's insurance (if any) on the rental ?

Comment: It's obviously going to depend on the policy, but as I said to Flimzy, I'm willing to bet that your existing coverage for rental cars only covers you if you are an authorized driver.

Comment: @Flimzy the bigger question is if the police officer will read into the T&C rather than checking the name on the insurance.

Comment: @JonathanReez: If a ticket is involved, whether the police reads the T&C is probably irrelevant.

Comment: If an accident is involved, the insurance company will certainly read the T&C and won't pay out if the policy is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

The rental agency is the only one who can answer this question.  Technically, you could be driving a stolen car.

Note, many agencies automatically allow spouses and business associates to drive a car without being specifically authorized on the rental agreement.  *You have to ask the agency about this.*

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. The rental agency has no control over the police and is unlikely to provide an honest response to a question on how to break their rules.

Comment: I suppose, then the specific question is unanswerable since it's at the discretion of the officer and his/her effort to verify the status of the driver.  The renter should also know all the rules and benefits, specifically for spouses.

Comment: But the question is whether or not the police cares about who's behind the  wheel, as long as the main driver is present. That's perfectly answerable.

Comment: @Johns-305, although many allow this _for free_, you still _must_ register those people when taking out the car (or later, but before they drive). I do that all the time.; the companies all insist on seeing the drivers license of each such person before they are added for free.

Comment: @Aganju.  No, this is not the case.   Which is why you have to ask.